# C# Custom Marshaling - ICustomMarshaler implementation not supplied with zero IntPtr values

Tags: c#, julia, marshalling, dllimport

I've implemented a very simple custom marshaler for an API:

Custom Marshaler:

```
  private sealed class JuliaWrapperMarshaller : ICustomMarshaler
  {
      object ICustomMarshaler.MarshalNativeToManaged(IntPtr pNativeData) => (JuliaWrapper)pNativeData;

     [other methods removed]  
  }
```

API:

```
    [DllImport(@"libjulia.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(JuliaWrapperMarshaller))]
    public static extern JuliaWrapper jl_eval_string(string str);
```

And this works fine when the `jl_eval_string` method returns a non-zero IntPtr. I can convert it to my return object `JuliaWrapper` and all is well.

---

The problem comes when I execute `jl_eval_string` with invalid parameters and it returns a zero IntPtr.

I want to handle this in my `JuliaWrapper` object and automatically call 'get last error'. However I don't get the chance to, **because the `ICustomMarshaler.MarshalNativeToManaged` method is never invoked when the `jl_eval_string` method returns `0x0000`**

- Is there a way of telling the custom marshaler to provide me with 0 IntPtr values?
- Are there any hacks to work around this?
- Is there a better way of working?

Comment: cast pNativeData to a object first so you can test if it is null. You can later cast it again to your wrapper

Comment: @jdweng See the bold part of my question: When jl_eval_string returns 0, the MarshalNativeToManaged method is not even invoked. I have a breakpoint on there that isn't hit.

Comment: So it is not return a null pointer, instead the value is zero.  A pointer (IntPtr) is an int32 while the code is returning a int16 with a value of zero.

Comment: @Jon The earlier comments can safely be ignored, this user regularly writes comments on pinvoke questions that make it clear that he has never once written a pinvoke declaration!!

Comment: As for your problem, I'd recommend manual marshaling here.

Comment: No can do, [this test](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/604a34b497219551a20abe266337b64e7124dac6/src/vm/custommarshalerinfo.cpp#L180) defeats it.  Do make sure that this is not what you want, turning a native null into a managed null tends to be the right choice.  If not then you'll have to declare the return type as IntPtr then marshal with Marshal.PtrToStructure() when it is not null.  Don't forget to release native memory as needed.  Note that you can now also declare the wrapper as a struct, might be useful.

Comment: @HansPassant - thanks for that link. I was searching for the calling code to see what actually happens prior couldn't find it anywhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Hans' comment, this isn't possible.

In order to achieve similar functionality, I created public/private shadow functions which return my wrapper class.

[image]

The `implicit operator` function receives the IntPtr which is 0 or otherwise, and calls the constructor of my wrapper class, which I then have code in to handle calling 'GetLastError' if the IntPtr is 0.

[image]